# Cakephp : Error: The requested address '/cakephp/options/edit/1' was not found on this server

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following Edit method in option controller

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Option->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid option'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        if ($this->Option->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The option has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The option could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {

        $options = array('conditions' => array('Option.' . $this->Option->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->Option->find('first', $options);
    }
}
```

when i try to access url ( options/edit/1 ) , it throw me an error that `Error: The requested address '/cakephp/options/edit/1' was not found on this server.`, and the strange that the index view is working just fine .

I tried to trace the error and i found that the following lines of code is matched

```
if (!$this->Option->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid option'));
    }
```

That means that the `options.id` is not exist in the database, while the id is exist in the database , i checked many times

Here you can find the full error stack

> Invalid option
>   Error: The requested address '/cakephp/options/edit/1' was not found on this server.
>   Stack Trace
>   [internal function] → OptionsController->edit(string)
>   CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 490 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(OptionsController, array)
>   CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 191 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)
>   CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 165 → Dispatcher->_invoke(OptionsController, CakeRequest)
>   APP/webroot/index.php line 108 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)

What is the problem here ?

## Update

I tried to change the `exist` function with the following function ( `$this->Option->findAllById($id)` ) and it turn that it's working just fine

so the problem seem to be with the exist function ..

Comment: This is going to turn out to be a head-table solution. If you're _sure_ the row exists then the query triggered by `$this->Option->exists` is either looking at the wrong table, wrong database or otherwise not matching the row you're looking at. Check (inside the if, before throwing an exception) what the sql log is to identify the exact reason.

Comment: i added the a sql before the `if` and i found that it's working just fine and got the first `option.id` from the table , so there is no problem with the database connection, also i mentioned that the index view is working ok ( retrieving the data from the database )

Comment: the sql done here is `SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`first_name`, `User`.`last_name`, `User`.`birth_date`, `User`.`about_me`, `User`.`photo`, `User`.`photo_dir` FROM `cakephp`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`id` = 1`

Comment: Thst is not the sql from the exists call. Check the error log to identify the _actual_ cause of the error (add the error and stacktrace to the question), or just enable debug to read it in the browser - it is not the exists call. Also please confirm it's a cakephp error message - are you looking at a standard apache error page? If so it's not the php code but the webserver config you need to investigate.

Comment: @AD7six Thank you for your help , the sql from the sql log i got from debug plugin in cakephp, i enabled the error for cakephp and you can find the full error stack.

Comment: Well: The error being thrown _is_ from that if block with the exists call; the sql in the comment above **is not** from the exists call (exists issues a count the above is not a count) - something is being missed. The simplest way to identify what's happening is to just debug [the exists method](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L2781) and verify that a) it doesn't return false early b) it does issue a fine call c) why that find call returns false. You may find the #cakephp irc channel (freenode) more appropriate to your needs. Good luck =).